# how do i fixe Page Builder on a custom page?

Tags: plugins, page-template

hi i create a theme from scratch for wordpress (with header and footer)
i did my home-page  but for the other page i wanted to keep the header and the footer and using Page Builder for the content but its seem i cant display the Page builder here the code of my custom page :

```
<?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */ 
 get_header();
 ?>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

so i keep the header and the footer for the page but won't display the page builder element
[image]

how can i fixe this issue 
thanks

Comment: There's nothing inbetween the `get_header` and `get_footer` call, not even a standard post loop, is this intentional?

Comment: i'm quite novice in wordpress and code in general i was following a tuto to create my theme for a job  so i think that if you use the plugin he will automaticly display the php in the page so i try to figure what should i put between header and the footer to make the plugin working

Comment: Start with a standard post loop, plugins can't just insert PHP, they need something they can work with

Comment: I think you need to call the_content there, then only the content will be visible there.